# App crashes when I add a Activity indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm writing an app and ind the app I got a Web View and I want to add an Activity Indicator. So I use this code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) 
         target:self selector:@selector(loadingPage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But when I insert this code my app crashes and refers me to this code:

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

at the line that starts with "int retVal..." it tells me "Thread 1: Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT"". By the way this code that it shows me is not something I wrote it was in the Xcode project from the beginning.

So my question is: Does anyone know a simple way of fixing this or another simple way of adding a Activity Indicator?

If someone knows a better way pleace write the code since I'm new to app development and still have allot to learn.

In advance thank you very much :)

Here's some more code:

.h file

```
@interface Ugeblad : UIViewController {

    // Web View
    IBOutlet UIWebView *faktaPDF;

    // Activity Indicator View
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *pageLoadingIndicator;


    NSTimer *timer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *faktaPDF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *pageLoadingIndicator;

@end
```

.m file

```
[faktaPDF addSubview:pageLoadingIndicator];

[faktaPDF loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Website"]]];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loadingPage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I see no reference of any activity indicator in your code, and your crash is not happening in main. Look carefully at the console. Also, more code around your NSTimer code might be useful. And the loadingPage method as well.

Comment: You need to post more code, more likely than not you are overreleasing something (or not retaining something)...and its prolly your timer..

Comment: You should post the code for loadingPage method.

Answer (score 1):

If by activity indicator you mean a spinning wheel (known as the UIActivityIndicatorView), you don't need a timer for it. It animates on its own; you just have to place it on the view and call [startAnimating].

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an NSTimer for this, that's gross. Assign yourself as the delegate of the UIWebView and implement

`-webViewDidStartLoad:` to present your "loadingView" and then implement

`-webView:didFinishLoad:` and `-webView:didFailLoadWithError:` to hide your "loadingView".